# How to change openjdk in exported docker tar file

Tags: docker, tar

I have docker image in a tar file that I load to a docker container.

I am trying to update openjdk and java version in it. After I un-tar the file I can not see any Dockerfile in it, Only Layers, manifest and hex json file. is there a way to update the jave and openjdk in it?

Thanks

Comment: The best approach by far is to get the original Dockerfile and update that.  If the image just contains a JVM plus a jar file, you could reconstruct this fairly straightforwardly.